# Received NaN for the `children` attribute

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to avoid `forceUpdate()` when updating cart items. Which I've read it's the best practice.

So I'm updating with `onClick` the back-end `cart` array with `axios` then `setCart` hook and calling once again `setCart` to update the quantity in the front-end so React shows the actual quantity of the cart.

Getting this message:

> ```
> Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is
> expected, cast the value to a string.
>     in td (created by Cart)
>     in tr (created by Cart)
>     in tbody (created by Cart)
>     in table (created by ForwardRef)
>     in ForwardRef (created by Cart)
>     in div (created by Cart)
>     in div (created by Cart)
>     in Cart (created by App)
>     in Route (created by App)
>     in Switch (created by App)
>     in Router (created by HashRouter)
>     in HashRouter (created by App)
>     in App
> ```

Cart.js

```
const Cart = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    // more hooks
    
    const addOneMore = (i, id) => {
        
        axios
            .get(`cart/${id}/add`)
            .then((res) => {
                setCart(Object.values(res.data));
                const updatedCart = [...cart];
                updatedCart[i].quantity += 1;
                setCart(updatedCart);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        //code
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "15%" }}>
                <IndexNavbar />
                <h1>Tu vinos seleccionados</h1>
                {cart.length == 0 ? (
                    "No tienes vinos en el carrito"
                ) : (
                    <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" className="mt-3">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Sub-Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        {cart.map((product, i) => {
                            return (
                                <tbody key={i}>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <h5>{product.name}</h5>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <Button variant="success">
                                                {product.quantity}
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="link"
                                                onClick={() =>
                                                    addOneMore(i, product.id) // here is the issue
                                                }
                                            >
                                                <b>&nbsp; ¡Una más!</b>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button variant="link" size="sm">
                                                Eliminar
                                            </Button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {product.quantity * product.price}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Table>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If I increase the button without calling `axios` -which doesn't help me- I wouldn't have this problem, like so:

```
const addOneMore = (i, id) => {
        
        let updatedCart = [...cart];
        updatedCart[i].quantity += 1;
        setCart(updatedCart);
```

I've seen little posts about this issue.

**UPDATE**

Providing second argument to `useEffect` which originally sets `cart` when mounting causes the same issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("cart")
        .then((res) => {
            setCart(Object.values(res.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setError(err.message);
        });
}, [cart]);

const addOneMore = (i, id) => {
    axios
        .get(`cart/${id}/add`)
        .then((res) => {
            //removed new array
            setCart(Object.values(res.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setError(err.message);
        });
};
```

It updates the `state` but logs same error plus this extra error when jumping to a different route (eg. `"/"`)

> react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: Can't perform a React state
> update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a
> memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and
> asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> in Cart (created by App)

Thanks,

**UPDATE 2 - SOLVED**

In case is helpfull for someone I solved by setting state in `setCart` with the `axios - reponse` but with the newly formed `array`.

```
// add one more item to cart - update

    const addOneMore = (i, id) => {
        axios
            .get(`cart/${id}/add`)
            .then(() => {
                const updatedCart = [...cart];
                updatedCart[i].quantity += 1;
                setCart(updatedCart);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(err.message);
            });
    };

    const removeItem = (productToRemove, productId) => {
        axios
        .get(`/cart/${productId}/destroy`)
        .then(() => {
            setCart(cart.filter((product) => product !== productToRemove)); // remove just that product from cart
        })
        .catch( err => {
            setCart( err.message );
        })
    }
```

Thanks to @Jacob Smit for the hint.

Comment: Change `const updatedCart = [...cart];` to `const updatedCart = Object.values(res.data);` and remove `setCart(Object.values(res.data));`. These two changes should ensure that `updatedCart` is the new information and not stale information when you finally set the state with `setCart(updatedCart);`.

Comment: Doing that will just add 1 to `cart` after the `get` method which will cause my cart to have -falsely- one extra cart item, which in the end won't show anyway and I will be the lead to the same issue once again.

Comment: I must correct myself. I didn't understand your response but It actually helped me. I had to avoid using `setCart` with the `axios - response`, but with the newly formed `array`.